# Updating multiple row with random data from another table?

Tags: sql-server, random, sql-update

Combining some examples, I came up with the following query (fields and table names have been anonymised soI hope I didn't insert typos).

```
UPDATE destinationTable
SET destinationField = t2.value
FROM destinationTable t1
CROSS APPLY (
    SELECT TOP 1 'SomeRequiredPrefix ' + sourceField as value
    FROM #sourceTable
    WHERE sourceField <> ''
    ORDER BY NEWID()
    ) t2
```

**Problem**
Currently, all records get the same value into `destinationField` , value needs to be random and different. I'm probably missing something here.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a possible solution. Using CTE's assign row numbers to both tables based on random order. Join the tables together using that rownumber and update the rows accordingly.

```
;WITH 
dt AS 
(SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY NEWID()) AS RowNum
FROM dbo.destinationtable),
st AS
(SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY NEWID()) AS RowNum
FROM dbo.#sourcetable)

UPDATE dt
SET dt.destinationfield = 'SomeRequiredPrefix ' + st.sourcefield
FROM dt
JOIN st ON dt.RowNum = st.RowNum
```

**UPDATED SOLUTION**

I used `CROSS JOIN` to get all possibilities since you have less rows in source table. Then assign random rownumbers and only take 1 row for each destination field.

```
;WITH cte
AS
(
    SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY destinationfield ORDER BY NEWID()) AS Rownum
    FROM destinationtable
    CROSS JOIN #sourcetable
    WHERE sourcefield <> ''

)

UPDATE cte
SET cte.destinationfield = 'SomeRequiredPrefix ' + sourcefield
WHERE cte.Rownum = 1

SELECT * FROM dbo.destinationtable
```

Comment: This is working better but not yet doing everything it should. Data are randomise but #sourcetable as far less records the destination table, hence I'm thinking of using a LEFT OUTER JOIN, otherwise #sourceTable is limiting the number of row update in destinations table. Still it seems important to keep "WHERE sourceField <> ''" since a lot of source records have '' in sourceField.

Comment: Yet are you sure it's "UPDATE dt"? "Not UPDATE destinationtable"?

Comment: In ST: 3.000 in total, but really a lot where sourceField = [blank string]. In DT ~82.000.
For now I went for a cursor instead of a single query.

Comment: @TTT I've added another possible soluition.

Comment: With that one I get (547 row(s) affected), where I should have (82067 row(s) affected). Also the execution time of a cursor is 00:19, the execution time of the updated solution is 00:55, so for now I'm staying with the cursor.